# Can't find Apple LLVM 8.0 - Custom Compiler Flags in target build settings

Tags: ios, xcode, llvm

I'm trying to find the Apple LLVM 8.0 - Custom Compiler Flags in my project's target build settings. I'm using Xcode 8.2.1. I need it because I have to add some flags as I am using SQLCipher in my project. Whereas the sqlcipher.xcodeproj has its own Custom Compiler Flags options. Here is the the screenshots of sqlcipher build settings.

[image]

I need to define C flags under Other C Flags in my build settings. Also I have tried with a new project using Xcode 8.2.1 but the options are absent.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At last I found it. You have to search by **Custom Compiler Flags** .

[image]